Convergence of coupons
In the well-known coupon collector problem with $n$ coupons, I want to understand the probability that, given that I have already collected coupon $j$, I will collect it again before collecting all coupons.
This is:
Pr(coupon j will appear 1-times more before the end)
Pr(coupon j will appear 2-times more before the end)
Pr(coupon j will appear k-times more before the end)
call this probability $\Pr(x=k)$ in short.
I want to compute
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Pr(x=i) \cdot \frac{1}{i+1}$$
I suppose a way to do this is Pr(x=1) is that in each subsequent round, I do not get that coupon with probability (n-1)/n in T-1 rounds and in exactly one round, I get it with probability $1/n$, so
$$\Pr(x=1)=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{T-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Pr(x=2)=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{T-2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\Pr(x=k)=\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{T-k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k+1}$$
I know that on average $T= n H_n$ from standard results. Can I prove that my expression $Y$ converges? I have a feeling it may converge to $1/e$.

The probability that you will get coupon $j$ again depends on how many coupons you have already obtained, but I don't see this mentioned anywhere in your question.
Suppose you have currently obtained $m$ out of the $n$ coupons, including coupon $j$. So $0<m<n$. There are $n-m$ coupons left, so the probability that you will get one of these before you get another coupon $j$ is $\frac{n-m}{n-m+1}$. Then you will have obtained $m+1$ out of the $n$ coupons, including coupon $j$, and so you can repeat the same logic. So the probability that you will finish the whole collection before getting another coupon $j$ is
$$\prod_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{n-k}{n-k+1}=\frac{1}{n-m+1}.$$
And so the probability that you will get another one of coupon $j$ before the end is
$$1-\frac{1}{n-m+1} = \frac{n-m}{n-m+1}.$$

Thanks for this, I am assuming j is the first coupon. Here I would get n-1/n simply, so it is the expression I had before. But good comment.
